# Get Result from Observable - Kotin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, observable

I have a method which returns on Observable as follows:

```
fun currentLocation(): Observable<LatLngFix> {
    if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ||
            !context.isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
        return getDefaultLocation()
    }

    // lastKnownLocation returns location or complete without result
    // in the latter case, return default unknown location
    return Observable
            .concat(locationProvider.lastKnownLocation.map {
                val latLng = LatLngFix(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                return@map latLng
            }, getDefaultLocation())
            .onErrorResumeNext { getDefaultLocation() }
            .first()
}
```

Then When I call this function, I would like to get the latlng variable. So I need to subscribe to the Observable oviously, but don't know why, the following gives an error:

```
localisationService.currentLocation().subscribe(latLng -> {

})
```

Saying that latLng is not defined. What's the right way of retrieving the value ?

Comment: This is no kotlin lambda function syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
localisationService.currentLocation().subscribe { latLng ->

}
```

(note the latLng argument inside the curly braces)

or

```
localisationService.currentLocation().subscribe ({ latLng ->

}, 
{ error -> 
})
```

if you also want to implement `onError`.